# Выгрузка из файла db в Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite, excel

Подскажите, как можно выгрузить из файла .db данные в Excel?

К примеру база такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам поможет библиотека Pandas, изучайте подключение к БД и сохранение в Exel. У вас .db это какая то база данных? или плоский файл?

Comment: О какой БД идёт речь?

Comment: @garrythehotdog плоский файл

Comment: @MaxU просто открыл программу DB Browser for SQLite и создал там таблицу

Comment: так у Вас файл или БД? Вы можете уже определиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), как вам уже посоветовали в комментариях:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/test.db')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name', conn)
df.to_excel(r'd:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

для <s>извращенцев</s> апологетов не очень понятных однокомандных решений:

```
(pd.read_sql('select * from table_name', sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/test.db'))
   .to_excel(r'd:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False))
```

NOTE: для полноценной работы с Excel в Pandas рекомендуется установить следующие модули:

```
pip install xlrd xlwt xlsxwriter openpyxl
```

Comment: Если файл не sql а .db ?

Comment: @DDDsss, название файла может быть любым, главное, чтобы внутри был SQLite

Comment: Я расставил пути к файлам, но выдает ошибки, посмотрите пожалуйста, закрепил сверху